# Running LaTeX via command line on Ubuntu server

Tags: server, 10.04, latex

On an Ubuntu 10 server (yes, not the latest version anymore), I would like to run LaTeX so that I can invoke the program via command line and pass .tex files to compile. Is this possible?

TeX Live would be one of the distributions that you can choose, right?

I can just install it with the following command, can't I?

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

And then? How can I invoke TeX Live via command line, without a GUI (as this is on a remote server)?

Comment: Try `man latex`. Also texlive comes with a lot of documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that command will install a basic but fully functional `LaTeX` environment.

You then compile a document `mydoc.tex`:

```
latex mydoc
latex mydoc
```

Which will produce a `dvi` file which you can further convert to postscript with `dvips`. (Or other output formats, eg `png` with `dvipng`.) In the more likely event that you want PDF output, use `pdflatex` instead of `latex`. (I assume this is available in 10.04, I don't have a copy on hand to check).

If you are running on a server, you might want the option `-interaction=nonstopmode`, otherwise it will pause and wait for your input if it finds an error in the document.

It is necessary to run `latex`/`pdflatex` more than once since during the first pass it will produce various auxiliary files which it then uses to improve the layout the next time around.

More detailed questions about latex are probably best asked on the [appropriate stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked fine, but although you said I have to run `pdflatex` more than once, the PDF is always there after the first run. So is running it once enough after all?